# Master's in Mathematical Finance

Tags: soft-question

**Question:** I currently graduated with a Bachelor's in mathematics. I have taken classes in analysis up to and including introduction to measure and integration theory, probability theory without measure theory, point-set topology, complex analysis, pdes, and introductory abstract algebra, as well as an intro to mathematical data science. Now I am looking to pursue a master's degree in mathematical finance. I would like to ask what are the job positions one can hold with the latter degree?